# Is there a JSON serializer in the Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, json, serialization, silverlight-3.0

I really want this so I can serialize / deserialize some complex data objects using JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `JsonReaderWriterFactory` is supported in Silverlight 3: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.jsonreaderwriterfactory(VS.95).aspx

Answer (score 0):

We have used [Json.NET](http://www.codeplex.com/Json)

It's pretty handy for serializing objects back and forth from Javascript on the client to C# on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use DataContractJsonSerializer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.95).aspx)